# OpenCV +Python take sample automatically

Tags: python, opencv, real-time, face-recognition

I want to take some sample of face image from webcam. I want to take about 8 samples. So when i press button "s", it will take 8 samples. So i try to make looping like this:

```
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
ROI = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
nameUser = raw_input("Input yourname: ")
for i in range(0,8):
    i_string = str(i)
    cv2.imwrite(nameUser+i_string+'.jpg',ROI)
    time.sleep(3)
```

But 8 image that i got all is exactly same. There is a way to make program take sample face but not exactly same?

Comment: your ROI is always the same. in which way *should* they differ ? maybe you need to explain that first.

Comment: That is the problem. Why ROI always same although I give delay 3 seconds, everytime take 1 sample. I mean in 3 seconds delay, frame from camera certainly change, right?

Comment: you need to take a fresh image from the camera each time. (and also, probably do a new facedetection for each sample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think, it's just a logic problem, try to re-organize it:

```
recording = 0 # use it as a flag/counter

while(True):
    ok, frame= cap.read();
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
        recording = 8
        nameUser = raw_input("Input yourname: ")

    if recording >= 0 && len(faces)>0:
        ROI = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        i_string = str(recording)
        cv2.imwrite(nameUser+i_string+'.jpg',ROI)
        recording -= 1
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Thank you mr @berak yups it work. but but I think, i prefer use "if recording > 0:" than "if recording >=0:"

Comment: whatever ;). just don't forget to check, if there *was* a face detected !